# Capitalisation in common nouns that form part of a proper noun

Tags: punctuation

The word *region* is a common noun. In certain pairings, this common noun comes after a proper noun, as in 'the Highlands Region'. So *region* is now being specific: so the word is now capitalised because it forms part of a proper noun. Is this capitalisation correct, please?

Comment: It depends on how cohesive the two-orthogonal-word term is regarded as being. 'The British Isles' is a compound proper noun, but 'British islands' (as in 'there are over xxx British islands') is not. With non-obvious cases, a check in the literature is necessary.

Comment: A comparable formulation is "the San Francisco Bay Area," which usually appears with the word _Area_ initial-capped. But popular usage defines standard practice, and I don't know whether "the Highlands Region" is widely enough used to support capitalizing _Region_ as if it were part of the proper name or whether, on the other hand, the standard practice is to refer to the quasi-proper name of the region as simply "the Highlands."

Answer (score 1):

The British Isles (as Edwin Ashworth just said), the Burning Man, the Rocky Mountains; but the British public, the American coastline, German cuisine.  It just depends on whether the entire phrase is a proper name.

Apparently "the Highlands Region" in New Jersey and "the Highlands Region" in Papua New Guinea are both proper names.